# In Rails ActiveRecord Migrations, `using:` keyword

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, database-migration, rails-migrations

It's been decided to update certain fields from `int` to `bigint`.
Rails can't automatically reverse this kind of migration and so suggests we have to create both an `up` and a `down` action along with adding a `using:`. 
 The problem is that I honestly can't seem to find documentation on what `using:` does nor what the suggestion rails makes actually means (beyond what I can infer).

With that in mind, in the following example:

- What does `using:` mean?
- What does the `SQL` in the `String` used in as the value of `using:` mean? (I can infer but I want the actual definition)

```rb
class UpdateModelFieldType < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    reversible do |dir|
      dir.up do
        change_column :model,
                      :field,
                      :bigint,
                      using: 'field::bigint', algorithm: :concurrently

      end

      dir.down do
        change_column :model,
                      :field,
                      :int,
                      using: 'field::int',
                      algorithm: :concurrently
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, I can't find anything in the [official docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/) about the `:using` option but I can tell you what it does and point you at the PostgreSQL documentation instead.

The `using: expr` option adds a USING clause to the ALTER TABLE statement that gets sent to the database to change the column's type so that you get:

```
alter table models alter column fields type bigint using 'field::bigint'
```

instead of just:

```
alter table models alter column fields type bigint
```

So what does the USING clause do? The [fine manual says](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html):

> `SET DATA TYPE`
>   This form changes the type of a column of a table. [...] The optional USING clause specifies how to compute the new column value from the old; if omitted, the default conversion is the same as an assignment cast from old data type to new. A USING clause must be provided if there is no implicit or assignment cast from old to new type.

So the `using: expr` option tells the database how to convert old column values to values in the new type.

Now what does `field::bigint` mean? That's a [PostgreSQL-specific type cast](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS). The standard SQL version would be `cast(field as bigint)`.

Comment: Thank you, as I said, I could infer a lot of it but I wanted a more specific dictionary like-answer.